# How can I add Total value of certain category column in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

My query:

```
SELECT goods
,       membership 
,       total
FROM tbl1
WHERE membership = 'GROUP'

UNION ALL 

SELECT goods
,       membership
,       total
FROM tbl1
WHERE membership = 'NON-GROUP'
```

[image]

My webservices :

```
$count = 0; $total = 0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($empRecords)) {
$total=$row['total'];
   $data[] = array(
"goods"=>htmlspecialchars($row['goods']),
"membership"=>htmlspecialchars($row['membership']),
"total"=>htmlspecialchars(number_format((float)$row['total'], 2, '.', ',')),    
   );

$count++;
      if($count>=2)
      {
        $data[] = array(
        "goods"=>htmlspecialchars(""),
        "membership"=>htmlspecialchars("SUBTOTAL          :"),
        "total"=>htmlspecialchars(number_format((float)"$total", 2, '.', ',')), //still wrong value 
        );
        $count=0;
      }
}
```

The problem is, I want to add subtotal value based on goods. I tried adding inside while, but it keeps counting all the total not by goods. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Amend your query to include an ORDER BY clause. Then, just start a loop. Record totals in a variable (similar to your $count). Then, whenever goods changes, just print and reset that variable.

Comment: Incidentally, your present query appears to be functionallly identical to `SELECT goods
     , membership 
     , total
  FROM tbl1
 WHERE membership IN('GROUP','NON-GROUP')
 ORDER 
    BY goods
     , membership;``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer. All I have to do is mirror the $count variable, but to add values, not rows.

```
$count = 0; $total = 0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($empRecords)) {
$total= $total + $row['total']; //add each specific column
   $data[] = array(
"goods"=>htmlspecialchars($row['goods']),
"membership"=>htmlspecialchars($row['membership']),
"total"=>htmlspecialchars(number_format((float)$row['total'], 2, '.', ',')),    
   );

$count++;
      if($count>=2)
      {
        $data[] = array(
        "goods"=>htmlspecialchars(""),
        "membership"=>htmlspecialchars("SUBTOTAL          :"),
        "total"=>htmlspecialchars(number_format((float)$total, 2, '.', ',')), //return result here
        );
        $count=0;
        $total=0; //stop or reset the addition value of total for each goods category.
      }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like maybe MySQL's `ROLLUP` functionality might be close to what you want here:

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(goods, 'grand total') AS goods,
    CASE WHEN goods IS NOT NULL THEN COALESCE(membership, 'subtotal') END AS membership,
    SUM(total) AS total
FROM yourTable t
GROUP BY
    t.goods,
    t.membership;
```

Comment: how can I do it using PHP? It worked but I want to put it in Subtotal

Comment: You shouldn't need to do much to make it work in PHP.  Just access the aliases in the select clause, which are `goods`, `membership`, and `total`.

Comment: Am I missing something here?

Comment: @Strawberry Ask Donald Sutherland at the end of body snatchers `:-P`